# How to render a large amount of html after hitting search button?

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a recipe search app but I am not sure how to render the big chunk of html representing the 30 recipes I want to have displayed. These recipe card obviously have to change based on what kind of meal I search for. How do I Implement the html into my Js so I can make it change based on the meal type?

I tried to do it with insertAdjecentHTML but since it doesn't replaces the old page with the recipe on but rather ads on to it. It didn't worked:
Nevertheless here is the code:

```
// recipe card markup
const renderRecipe = () => {
  const markup = `
  <div class="recipe-results__card">
    <div class="recipe-results--img-container">
      <img
        src="${data.data.hits.recipe.image}"
        alt="${data.data.hits.recipe.label}"
        class="recipe-results__img"
      />
    </div>
    <p class="recipe-results__categories">
      ${limitCategories}
    </p>
    <h2 class="recipe-results__name">
      ${data.data.hits.recipe.label}
    </h2>
  </div>
  `;
  DOM.recipeGrid.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", markup);
};


// fn to display the markup for every search res
export const renderResults = recipes => {
    recipes.forEach(renderRecipe);
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. concatenate (push to an array) the HTML so you have ONE update
2. You can use innerHTML instead of insertAdjacent to replace the content

```js
let html = [];
data.data.hits.forEach(recipe => {
  html.push(`
  <div class="recipe-results__card">
    <div class="recipe-results--img-container">
      <img
        src="${recipe.image}"
        alt="${recipe.label}"
        class="recipe-results__img"
      />
    </div>
    <p class="recipe-results__categories">
      ${limitCategories}
    </p>
    <h2 class="recipe-results__name">
      ${recipe.label}
    </h2>
  </div>
  `) });
document.getElementById("recipeGrid").innerHTML = html.join("");
```

Comment: I tried that too but  it is not my goal to replace the content of f.e. the home page with the search results but rather to load a completly new one. So that I can navigate back to Home without losing its content. When searching for something here, a new page gets loaded. https://chobanifoodservice.com/. Thank you for your Time ;)

Comment: It is react. The URL itself is updated but the page is not, just the search result. So based on the URL, the page can render a new search result and navigation will handle this. It is performing a new search each time (it COULD have cached the result and just rendered it)

Comment: So there is no possibility to do the same with plain js? And there in no possibility to just load a new page when searchin for the recipe results?

Comment: Yes you can do this in plain JS. you can search based on the URL and you can use the [history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) api to manipulate the URL or use [HASH or SEARCH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location#Example_5_Send_a_string_of_data_to_the_server_by_modifying_the_search_property) (which is what it was for)

Comment: I am. But only to get the recipe data from edamam api. This is my first time trying to write asynchronous code. I still got to learn quite a lot to really get my head around all of this. That's why I have to ask three times to understand it...

Comment: I am guessing in the code above that `data.data.hits` is an array of recipes

Comment: Ok, I am going to try to implement it. Thank you very much for your help! If I can't manage to get it up and running i'll get back to you if your ok with it.

Comment: they want an API key so I did not create a working example